# Eloquent update in laravel without deleting the old content

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the status attribute in my class. When creating a new instance, using 'create', I pass an array to the status.

```
class email extends Eloquent{

    protected $table = 'emails';
    protected $fillable = array(
        'status',
    );
}
```

And this is the result

```
"status": {
  "sent": false,
  "deleted": false,
  "silent": false
}
```

I'm trying to do this to update only one of the statuses.

```
$dest= email::where('uid', "5040")->update(['status.sent'=>true]);
```

But this produces a result I would not like.

```
"status": {
  "sent": true
}
```

All previously written content has been deleted, how to get this result.

```
"status": {
  "sent": true,
  "deleted": false,
  "silent": false
}
```

I have an idea of querying the bank and getting the status array, storing it, changing it, and updating it, but that would make me query the bank twice. One fetching the array, the other updating. There is a way, like 'spread'(...). Or something more correct and simple.

Comment: What is the data type for the status column?

Comment: $mensage['status'] = ['sent'=>false,'deleted'=>false,'silent'=>false];

Comment: No, what is the data type in the database?

Comment: @Aynber array, i think

Comment: @Aynber it's actually a json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Model add `$casts`

```php
protected $casts = [
    'status'=>'array'
];
```

and then

```php
$dest = email::where('uid', "5040")->update(['status->sent' => true]);
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#updating-json-columns

Comment: I made the change and on update, $dest returns 1 without error, but status remains false, no update.

Comment: @RicardoSpinola which laravel version are you using ?

Comment: @RicardoSpinola have you added casts in email model ?

Comment: yes, I'm doing status and receiving its array that way, when creating the instance of the class. $mensage['status'] = ['sent'=>false,'deleted'=>false,'silent'=>false];

Comment: @RicardoSpinola i have added ref of document .it should work.and in laravel 8 i tested it ,it works

Comment: @RicardoSpinola .in database table set  status data type to text

Comment: I changed from '->', to '.' and array to text and it worked

Comment: @RicardoSpinola okay.finally solved yourself :)